# Module not found and something seems wrong with my PATH

Tags: python

I am trying to import a package to VScode in python.
This is giving me a module not found error.
I have tried pip install genanki and genanki has already been installed. Then I located the pip which on my mac is
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip
I thought maybe I needed to reset my Path so then I in my terminal echo %PATH%
and it returned /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
I watched a video that explained how I can include my pip into the PATH but I am unsure how and I am not even sure this will resolve my problem.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please show the stacktrace, the command you're running and maybe the file structure of your project.

Comment: [virtualenv](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtualenv+on+windows) fixes and prevents this stuff

Comment: Thank you for your help I have now fixed this problem by uninstalling python and then reinstalling the newest version.